# Not able to set state as array of objects inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting data from word press API then I structure the data inside the map function. I am not able to set state as array of objects inside map function I
get Arrays of different objects or Objects of different objects but not a single
Array of Objects

```
  const rsp = response.data;

  const map = rsp && rsp.map(item => {
    let struct = {};
    let data = [];
    const id = item.id;
    const title = item.title['rendered'];
    const image = item['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url;
    const banner = item.ACF.banner_image.url;
    const products = item.ACF.celebrity_products;


    let store={
      id:id,
      title:title,
      image:image,
      banner:banner,
      products:products
    };


    setRes(prevState => {

      // struct['data'] =store;
      // data.push(store);
      return{ ...prevState,
      id: store.id,
      name: store.title,
      uri: store.image,
      banner: store.banner,
      products: store.products


  }})

  });
```

Comment: I'm confused.. `setRes` is mutation method on `useState`? You're calling it on each iteration? Not a good idea.. Also, if I understand this currectly, you're trying to set state as an array but you're overwriting the state with single objects on each iteration. *Solution?* Use `setRes` after the iteration.

Comment: yes but after iteration i am not able to set it as state because map function returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd want more something like :

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])

rsp && setItems(rsp.map(item => ({
  id: item.id,
  name: item.title['rendered'],
  uri: item['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url,
  banner: item.ACF.banner_image.url,
  products: item.ACF.celebrity_products
})))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't provide the complete story of you code. but I think we can help.

if you intend to have the result of your processing as an array inside the map variable then you should've returned something inside it like

```js
let oddNumber = [ 1, 3, 5 ];
const map = oddNumber.map( oneOddNumber => { return oneOddNumber * 2; } );
// now map is [ 2, 6, 10 ]
```

or if you intend to save the array you want using `setRes` function then you should've done something like

```js
setRes(prevState => ({ 
    ...prevState,
    theResultArray: [...prevState.theResultArray, { id: store.id, ..... } ]
}))
```

and now you state have the property name `theResultArray` which is an array of object which you've iterated on.

hope you can provide more complete code so help can be more clear next time :D

Comment: i did the same thing it will return different arrays of different objects but i want a single array of objects

Comment: if you can provide the full code we hope we can help more then.